# Why do we need to name method arguments?

Tags: objective-c

What we have now:

```
@interface BGTest
-(void)someMethodWithName:(NSString *)methodName tag:(NSUInteger)tag path:(NSURL *)path;
@end
```

Why not to write:

```
@interface BGTest
-(void)someMethodWithName:(NSString *) tag:(NSUInteger) path:(NSURL *)
@end
```

It is stated that ObjC method names should be self documented, and they are. Why to write more if methods can be clearer with lesser code?

I mean, why do we need to name method arguments in interface part, but not just in implementation?

Comment: The second segment is the variable you're referencing within the method.

Comment: @remus, it's just a declaration, why bother?

Comment: Do you plan to use it in your method as a variable and do stuff with it? Then it matters.

Comment: @remus, I mean, why do we need to name method arguments in interface part, but not just in implementation?

Comment: Because the method isn't directly accessible to the compiler, you're essentially telling it what is available for it to reference. It needs to retrieve passed arguments in order to actually cascade them down to your method implementation.

Comment: @remus, compiler already knows which types will be used, so arg names are not so useful. it can just make something like this: arg[0] is NSString*, so pass first argument as NSString... arg[1] is NSData*, so pass an NSData* etc. It's not a problem.

Comment: @AndrewShmig, I would add it to the question: ` I mean, why do we need to name method arguments in interface part, but not just in implementation?`.

Comment: I think the answers have missed the point of your question. I assume in your second example you would refer to the values by their argument name, and under the hood the compiler could desugar the declaration to -(void)someMethodWithName:(NSString *)methodName tag:(NSUInteger)tag path:(NSURL *)path;. 

I do not know the answer, I suspect it is not in the spec to reduce ambiguity and make the compiler's job easier, or maybe no one ever thought of this particular sugar.

Comment: I agree they're not useful to the human reading it, but the compiler isn't built that way...

Comment: But I don't think that saving typing is a big goal of a language you only ever type in an IDE with tab-complete, and I don't think that adding this sugar improves readability. In fact, the current spec lets you declare the arguments just like they were variables and so it is more consistent with other parts of the language, IMO.

Comment: interestingly, if you give the arguments different names in the interface than you do in the implementation, it doesn't matter or break anything. So clearly the argument names in the interface are not really serving any purpose other than to provide a convention for discussion or documentation ("The first NSString parameter is used to..." gets lengthy compared to "*name* is used to)

Comment: @RobP, wait a sec :) ObjC is self documented language, so there will be no "The first NSString...", you already know the name (and the purpose) of the method argument - from its method name.

Comment: Just a sidenote, but if you really don't want to type some name in an interface, underscores are valid identifiers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare a method without a parameter name because in this case there is no way for the compiler to tell if the next token after the type is a parameter name or it is a part of the method name. Let me demonstrate it on this example:

```
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int)a secondParam:(int)b;
```

This is a correct method declaration. Now let's edit it as you propose:

```
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int) secondParam:(int);
```

It's pretty obvious for us what we mean. We can tell, that `secondParam:` is clearly a part of a method name. But Objective-C allows us to write a column after a space like this:

```
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int) secondParam :(int);
```

And this case (from my point of view) is not that clear anymore. Especially if we remove one more space:

```
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int)secondParam :(int);
```

Now it looks like `secondParam` is the name of the first parameter, and part of a method name is missing.
I guess, to make resolving such issues easier, Objective-C makes us write a complete method specification.
I think, they could've changed method declaration format a little bit, so that it allowed such declarations (I like your idea), but it is like this for now.

Still, you can use different variable names in `@interface` and in `@implementation`. So this:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int)a secondParam:(int)b;
@end

@implementation TestClass
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int)firstParam secondParam:(int)secondParam
{...}
@end
```

is legal.

P.S. By the way, @CodaFi's idea with using underscores as variablesNames could be nice in this case:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
-(void)testMethodWithParam:(int)_ secondParam:(int)_;
@end
```

The interesting thing is that it compiles, despite the fact that I use a single underscore for both variable names.

Comment: Great! I like your answer, but there is one BUT... why allow empty parts in method names? Disallowing empty parts in method names and allowing removal of param names will make it clearer and simpler? Do you agree?
So I am interested also in main reasons which pushed Apple to choose between one and other.

Comment: @AndrewShmig, I'm agree with you. I thought about it and I also think that this might be a solution. Actually, I was surprised, that Objective-C allows spaces before columns. I think it would be better if they implemented your idea. The only problem is that it might break some existing code (there might be some strange people out there, who insert spaces before columns for reasons science does't know :) ).

Comment: Because of the lack of a spec, we may never know, but I think it has to do with the set of invariants for prototypes versus objects.  A prototype in C says that the symbol is going to be defined somewhere in the final product, an interface says that an object exposes that method publically.  You can use prototypes to simulate interfaces, but ultimately an interface is a laxer contract.  One could also say that in the interest of self-documenting method names, the identifiers for the arguments give more context.  A method named -get: doesn't mean much, but -get:argumentInDatabase does.

Comment: @CodaFi, I guess, you are right and this limitation really could really be a consequence of some specification/implementation details. Still, I think, that it would be a nice feature to have as an option, if they implemented it. It would allow us to write cleaner code, while still being able to use declarations like `-get:argumentInDatabase`. It's a pity, I can't find a place to send a feature request :)

Answer (score 1):

Because then you could not access the arguments' values.  The `methodName`, `tag`, and `path` names are the variables that the arguments are stored in.  Your first example is similar to a C function like `someMethodWithNametagpath(NSString *name, int tag, NSURL *path)`, while your second would be `someMethodWithNametagpath(NSString*, int, NSUrl*)`.

Comment: my question is about declarations of methods. In C you can write hello(char, int, int).

Comment: @AndrewShrmig Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  I thought you were talking about the implementation.  And in C, it is true you can write `hello(char, int, int), but only in a prototype.  In the actual implementation of a function, the parameters have to have names.

Comment: And if you have a declaration "void hello (char, int, int)" I have no idea what the arguments are there for. I love reading code and _knowing_ what it means just be reading it. I hate it when people try to save a few keystrokes and make my job harder. Take a typewriting course.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason I can think of is to disambiguate from:

```
// A method named someMethodWithName:::
- (void)someMethodWithName:(NSString *) methodName :(NSUInteger) tag :(NSURL *)path;
```

which would look pretty close to what you suggest:

```
- (void)someMethodWithName:(NSString *) tag:(NSUInteger) path:(NSURL *);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question with a question, how does the compiler know that the name of the variable in your example is `methodName`? I personally think it would be `name`. How did the compiler magically omit the "with"? Is your hypothetical Objective-C compiler equipped with some language parsing technology that allows it to understand english? What if my native language is Spanish?

Moreover, what about this method:

```
 -(void)someMethodWithName: (NSString*) anotherMethodWithName: (NSString*);
```

What's the name of the second variable? `anotherMethodName`? How does the compiler know to omit the `with` but save the `another`?

What if you have an `ivar` named "methodName"? Now you have to choose between an intuitively named method and an intuitively named `ivar`.

Now, beginners to Objective-C have to learn a whole set of rules for figuring out the variable name from the message name. Worse still, the set of rules for generating argument names is probably too complex to put in the spec, and has to be up to the implementer of the language. Now, there might be *several* different sets of naming conventions depending on your compiler.

Comment: Why compiler should bother about names of method arguments?

Comment: @AndrewShmig Your question presupposes that the compiler is smart enough to know the names of the all the method arguments from the method signature, and that the name that it generates is always obvious and intuitive. My answer is trying to demonstrate that that assumption is flawed.

Comment: @CodaFi, hmm.. ok, we have some method which has 3 arguments. Compiler knows there types and the sequence in which params should be passed to this method. Why any compiler should bother about names in this case? Don't forget that we are talking about interface part, not an implementation.

Comment: @AndrewShmig ok I see your point about it just being in the interface, so the compiler doesn't need to know the name... but this still has problems. Now Xcode can't autocomplete the method name based on the header without you naming all your variables when you go to implement it in the .m, and if you realize that you need a new method argument while implementing the method you can't just copy and paste the new signature into the .h file.

Comment: @BenPious, method name is "myMethodWithName:tag:path:directory:", so, in implementation I need just to type "myMethod" and XCode will show me all methods which start with "myMethod" and I'll select needed one and tap Return key. Don't see any problem at all. Yes, you need to name your params in interface, but you need to name any other passed arguments when you use autocompletion.

Comment: @AndrewShmig Yes, but how does it autocomplete when you are first implementing it when it doesn't have method argument names. It will not compile otherwise. "-(void)myMethodWithName:tag:path:directory:" is not valid syntax in a .m file. Now you are having to go back through the incorrect initial autocompletion and name your method arguments... no time has been saved.

Comment: @AndrewShmig What if you are making subclasses? It is more work to retype the same argument names for each subclass... assuming you actually named them the same each time. Imagine if you didn't, how annoying it will be to go from one subclass to another with different argument names for the same methods.

Comment: @BenPious, good point. Still, I think, it would be nice feature to have as an option.